# Is it possible to trace copy-pasted code to a website that it was retrieved from?

Tags: c++, copy, paste

If a person takes code from a website and pastes it in something like visual C++ and works on it and forms a finished working product. Could someone who has the source file take the source code from that finished product and trace the website that the leftover bits and traces of code were taken from?

When you copy and paste typed up code from a forum-esque website into something like visual C++ or eclipse does it hold within it an address of where it was copied from?

Comment: Try using some type of version control like `git` or `tfs`

Comment: Surely you can see why this wouldn't work?  Whole libraries that have been used illegally and copied exactly, maybe.  Short code snippets with variations, no way.

Comment: What if someone typed it and did not copy/pasted it?

Comment: If you think the person did not modify much of what he copy-pasted, you can _copy-paste_ the entire source code on Google Search, and the first result will generally be the website you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.

Unless the source code says "Hey, I came from this web site", there are no hidden, invisible bits anywhere in any source code that covertly indicate where it comes from.